# Where should Perl script point to when put on web server?

Tags: perl, hosting

I need to perform a scheduled backup of my MySQL database.

My web hosting service can run PHP and Perl scripts at chosen hours, so I've decided I would make a Perl script that would call `mysqldump`.

But in the first line of the Perl script I should put the location of the perl interpreter like `#!/usr/bin/perl` in Linux.

I didn't find the `perl` file in my `/` directory (I have `cgi-bin` directory).

What should I put in this path?

Comment: You can find the location by doing: `$ which perl` in your console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't `#!/usr/bin/perl` work for you? You really need to ask your service provider where they have installed perl. However, you will gain portability by using

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

instead, which will search the directories in `PATH` to establish where perl is installed on each platform.

Comment: Thanks. I actually didnt't managed to check #!/usr/bin/perl today (I thought this is more tricky) I will definitely try it tomorrow.

Comment: The main reason I use `#!/usr/bin/env perl` is that I have multiple versions of Perl installed, and I don't want to use the system Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can find the path using `whereis` command:

```
whereis perl
```

Mostly this yields `/usr/bin/perl` path if the installation was not customized.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

is the **shebang** line. Check out more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).